# React Native unit for text input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to add an unit to a `textInput` value:

[image]

---

I've tried to use the following, but didn't get any result:

```
value = { this.state.totalWeight + " Kgs"}
```

---

Also I tried to add the `" Kgs"` in `onSubmitEditing`:

```
onSubmitEditing={() => { 
    this.refs.firstInput.refs.value = this.state.totalWeight + " Kgs" 
}}
```

But again, no result!

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i use this way!

My `state`:

```
this.state = {
  commodity: "",
  isFilled: false
};
```

And then we have:

```
<TextInput
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  onChangeText={commodity =>
    this.setState({
      commodity,
      isFilled: false
    })
  }
  value={
    this.state.isFilled ? this.state.commodity + " Unit" : this.state.commodity
  }
  onFocus={() => this.setState({ isFilled: false })}
  onEndEditing={() => {
    if (this.state.commodity == "") {
      this.setState({ isFilled: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isFilled: true });
    }
  }}
  placeholder="Commodity"
/>;
```

Now every time the user enter a text, after editing, the UNIT will be added.

Comment: You mean that the user can change the text color?

Comment: The `Unit` text is part of the `TextInput` value, so the user can select it and delete it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand the question :D - You can use 2 `<Text>` then

Answer (score 5):

```
state = {
   value: "",
   unit: "Kgs"
}
render(){
   return(
     <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}} >
            <TextInput value={this.state.value} onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({value})} />
            <View style={{marginRight: 10}} >
                <Text>{this.state.value === '' ? '' : this.state.unit}</Text>
            </View>
     </View>       
   );
}
```

Comment: So every time i type a number, i'll get a "Kgs"! - e.g. i type "23" and the value is: "2 Kgs 3 Kgs"

Comment: Ohh right! Let me update the answer. The solution might seem a little hacky to you.

Comment: The updated answer might not be what you actually want. But it serves the need in my opinion.

Comment: I know, thanks anyway! Let's see if there's a better way by someone else! :)